# Visual Studio 2015 RTM Cordova IOS Build Error - Could not find module 'Q'

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Visual Studio 2015 RTM, and I am working on a Cordova project.  My project works fine for Android, but I cannot get it to build for IOS.  I have figured out what the problem is, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

When I build for IOS it is sending the build to the remote build agent installed on my Mac computer, but it is returning the following error:

> Could not find module 'Q'.  Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools
>   for Apache cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try
>   building again.

Following it's suggestion and clearing the Cordova cache does not help.  I did some research and have found that it is a bug in the cordova_ios library.  Here is a link to the commit that fixed the error https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/commit/ed272032878959c90eb28ccc1490e96fb7b69287.

Basically what the issue is that the check_reqs.js file is require 'Q' (uppercase) instead of 'q' (lowercase).

I can work around the problem (and confirm that this is the problem) by doing the following:

- Copy my Cordova project over to my Mac computer.
- At the command line add IOS as a Cordova platform.
- Go to the /platforms/ios/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js file and change line 25 to be a lowercase 'q'.
- Build and run the project on the Mac.

What I don't know is how to fix this in Visual Studio so I can build from Visual Studio?  I have tried doing NPM updates on the computer that Visual Studio is installed on, but that has not fixed it.  I have also tried to manually add the IOS platform to my project via the Cordova command line, and then changing the same file that I change on the Mac, but that does not fix it either.

It looks like this issue if fixed in the latest version of the cordova_ios library, I just cannot figure out how to get Visual Studio and/or the remote build agent on my Mac to use the latest version of the cordova_ios library.

**Update**
It looks like this is a bug that other people are seeing with Cordova.  There are discussion about it [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/132#issue-59368079) and [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/484).  I can reproduce this on my Mac computer.  If I create a new Cordova project and add the iOS platform and try to build it for iOS I receive this error.  I can then correct the issue by opening the check_reqs.js file and changing the uppercase 'Q' to a lowercase 'q'.  However when I build from Visual Studio it sends the project across to the Mac with the incorrect check_req.js file and the build fails.  I cannot figure out how to correct this issue when doing a iOS build from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OSX machine has case a case sensitive filesystem you can hit this though a fix is in the works. (Most people do not turn on case sensativity.)

The fix you reference has not yet been released publicly. You can watch for a "platform" release here: http://cordova.apache.org/

Once the platform is released it is very likely a Cordova CLI update will also occur (ex: 5.1.2) so you can just update to that version via the config designer.

However, as an alternative you can add the following into your config.xml file to cause Cordova to use a different iOS platform version and then do a "clean" in VS to force it to take effect:

```
<engine name="ios" spec="3.9.0" />
```

3.8.0 is the currently released version.

A "DISCUSS" thread is already going for an iOS release - it should be out in the next couple of weeks.

You can try using the Git URI to get edge - but that could be buggy so exercise care:

```
<engine name="ios" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios.git" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we should simply do a patch release of Cordova with this bug fix. Will start a thread on the mailing list to see if a quick release is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try re-installing vs-tac? Here's the doc:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551(v=vs.140).aspx#vstac

Comment: I tried re-installing vs-tac and it did not correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What version of node do you have installed on the MAC machine? I have 0.12.2 and the require(Q) gets satisfied without any errors. Can you try installing a newer version of Node? Let me know.

Comment: Turns out Mac OS X filesystem can be case sensitive or case insensitive (default) and this will be a problem when its the former. Can you run diskutil info / to check if your filesystem is case sensitive using 
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71357/how-to-check-if-my-hd-is-case-sensitive-or-not

Comment: The Mac has node v0.12.7 which is the current version of Node.  The disk on the Mac is setup to be case sensitive.  Looks like this is not easy to change.